# How to make returned string from helper method not html encoded

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I'm using a C# helper method to check to see if the value of an input field should be prefilled or not. When the value gets returned, however, any special characters have been replaced with html (ie: & is now `&amp;`). I'm looking for a way to change this back to the special characters (ie: change `ab&amp;c` back to `ab&c`). I've tried HtmlDecode but it doesn't have any effect on the returned value.

The input field:

```
<input type="text" class=" form-textbox" id="input_4" name="q4_1Property" size="40" value="@Helpers.checkEmptyPreFill(queryinputvalue,"q4_1Property","ab&c")"/>
```

The helper method:

```
@helper checkEmptyPreFill(IEnumerable<dynamic> queryinputvalue, string field_id, string defaultval, int cloned = 0) {  

var reqValue = queryinputvalue.FirstOrDefault(r => r.field_name.Equals(field_id));
var return_value = "";

if(reqValue != null){
    return_value = reqValue.field_data;
} else {

    return_value = defaultval;

}

if(cloned == 1){
    return_value = "";
}

@return_value
}
```

Comment: HtmlDecode should be fine, what did you try?

Comment: I tried HttpUtility.HtmlDecode() on return_value and defaultval in the helpermethod

Comment: Did you return the result of the function?  It won't change the original string.

Comment: Yes, I returned the result of the function. But in the database the value in &, when it's returned from the helper method it's been changed to &amp;

Comment: There might be some other reason if your string is "&" it would not be converted to `&amp;` look at this mvc fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/V3RkWM

Comment: Agreed. I double checked and the value that's being sent to the helper method is & but when it's returned it's &amp; Not sure what's causing this but it appears to be something in this helper method

Answer (score 0):

instead of `@return_value`

Try

```
new MvcHtmlString(return_value)
```

> MvcHtmlString Represents an HTML-encoded string that should not be encoded again.

Look at [msdn documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.mvchtmlstring.aspx) for more details on MvcHtmlString()

Comment: Doing this gave me the following compiling error: Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MvcHtmlString' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Is there more I need to add to the helper method to make this work?

Comment: @BrianCanini Try `new System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString(return_value)`

Comment: That gave me this: Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'MvcHtmlString' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web.Mvc' (are you missing an assembly reference?)